# Unwanted Empty Modal on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Am working in PHP using a jquery dialogue as a modal to display my form errors.
Everything works fine and displays corrrectly except on page load... an empty modal is displayed.
If you close it then proceed to fill-in the form the modal works as it is intended, displaying errors (if any) when the submit button it clicked.
For the sake of brevity I've included only the relavent code.

Am seeking help on how to prevent the empty modal from displaying on page load. I've reviewed dozens of related submissions and attempted to try implementing them, with dismal results. In most cases they either have no effect, or end-up disabling the modal all together.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
<?php

/// php error checking and form processing here ///

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" name="inquiry" method="post">

/// form fields here ///

<ul class="actions">
<li><input type="submit" class="button small" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Inquiry" /></li>
</ul>

</form>

<div id="error" title="Form Errors:">
<?php
if (!empty($errors))
{
echo "<div style=\"padding:15px 15px 0 15px\">";
echo "<ul style=\"margin-bottom:20px\">";
foreach ($errors as $error)
echo "<li style=\"font-size:15px; padding:5px\">$error</li>";
echo "</ul></div>";
}
?>
</div>

<!-- JS at the end -->

<script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- ver: 1.11.3 -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  

<script>
$('#error').dialog({
height: 380,
width: 260,
modal: true,
resizable: false,
dialogClass: 'no-close error-dialog'
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513051/when-creating-a-dialog-with-jquery-how-do-i-hide-the-dialog-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prevent this by calling the `dialog` init just when the form is submitted using `$_POST["submit"]` like :

```
<script>
     <?php if( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) ){ ?> 
         $('#error').dialog({
             height: 380,
             width: 260,
             modal: true,
             resizable: false,
             dialogClass: 'no-close error-dialog'
         });
     <?php } ?>
</script>
```